# Multiple window domain authentication IIS server

Tags: c#

My application server is on domain like abcuat.local. Window authentication is working fine. Now I want to add one more domain like abc.domain. Port is already open for both domain. How we can implement this on IIS server or in the c# code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This configuration is not dependent on IIS.

What you have to do is to setup trust between the two domain controllers - which you want to use for windows authentication.

Please ensure that all the appropriate ports are open between the two domain controllers between the trusted domains.

You will find the port information and other details [in this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc773178(v=ws.10))

Once the domain trust is setup properly, the windows authentication would automatically work in IIS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I find trust relationship between domain